# Getting error in php login screen

Tags: php, mysql

I am following this tutorial [mybringback](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13130/android-mysql-register-and-login-php-scripts/) and in that look at the code of register.php v.02  and i have wamp server setup. whenever i try to run the code it gives me error [image: Screenshot of error].

I have changed $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; in config.inc.php but still it is not working.

My server is working, phpmyadmin is working and mysql is working too. I did check that using a sample site from internet but it didn't have any require statement.

Comment: Post the code from register.php

Comment: as it says, it just cant find the file config.inc.php in the location it is supposed to be. Are you sure the file is there?

Comment: the file is there in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\config.inc.php.  is file supposed to be at anywhere else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the config.inc.php file is not found.

If you go to the same folder that your register.php file is in, you should see the config file in there as well.

Comment: I did copy the file from phpmyadmin and then paste it in the same folder where my php files are kept and it solved the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Looking at the tutorial you referenced, you could copy the file and paste it with the register.php file, or change the register.php code to look in the apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4 folder (I think may be "..\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\config.inc.php").  I would personally make a copy of the file, IMHO.

Comment: I did copy the file and it worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the file as specified in the error message. Either install it in a directory in the include path or alter the include path so that it can be found.